# Add second database with website pullng information from both databases?

Tags: sql-server

So my website is currently pulling stock information from "J" warehouse in a database called InvWarehouse, now we want to add "JT", so that it pulls from both "J" and "JT"

We have a scheduled stored procedure called "[spc_Schedule_Update_Qty_Stock]"that runs script in the back ground updating new information to the website. When I executed the stored procedure it returned a value of 0, I'm not exactly sure what that means.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spc_Schedule_Update_Qty_Stock]
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE      item
    SET         QtyOnHand = CASE WHEN (inv.QtyOnHand - inv.QtyAllocated) < 0 THEN 0 ELSE (inv.QtyOnHand - inv.QtyAllocated) END--inv.QtyOnHand
    FROM        tb_Item item WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN  [105.255.132.000].SysproCompanyA.dbo.InvWarehouse inv WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON          inv.StockCode = item.sCode  COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 
    WHERE       inv.Warehouse in ('J','JT')
END
```

I expect the output of the following to be 9, if "J" has 7 belts and "JT" has 2, with what I did so far there's no change.

Comment: *"When I executed the stored procedure it returned a value of 0"* An SP that runs successfully returns `0`, unless the SP has been defined to return a different value. For a **system** SP, on failure they will return the appropriate error code.

Comment: [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: Hi @Larnu, should i remove the NOLOCK?

Comment: The article discusses that matter. Using `NOLOCk` should only be done when you know what it does, and the caveats behind it (seeing as you're asking "should i remove it" rather than explaining *why* you're using it, clearly means you don't know what it does) but using `NOLOCK` on an `UPDATE` statement is a really bad idea.

Comment: @Larnu i read on it, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do something like below. Your original query is doing calculation at individual warehouse level only. You have to aggregate the stocks at two warehouses and then you have to apply that for UPDATE operation.

```
;WITH WarehousesAvailability AS
(
  SELECT inv.StockCode, Sum(inv.QtyOnHand) AS QtyOnHand, Sum(QtyAllocated) AS QtyAllocated
FROM  [105.255.132.248].SysproCompanyA.dbo.InvWarehouse inv 
WHERE       inv.Warehouse in ('J','JT')
GROUP BY inv.StockCode
)
UPDATE      item
    SET         QtyOnHand = CASE WHEN (inv.QtyOnHand - inv.QtyAllocated) < 0 THEN 0 ELSE (inv.QtyOnHand - inv.QtyAllocated) END--inv.QtyOnHand
    FROM        tb_Item item 
    INNER JOIN  WarehousesAvailability  inv 
    ON          inv.StockCode = item.sCode  COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Comment: Sorry @Larnu, I copied and pasted the original query. I should have taken care on NOLOCK

Comment: WarehouseAvailablity is a CTE (Common Table Expression), which is holding the stock information of two warehouses together. It kind of becomes your reference for invwarehouse. invwarehouse is a table at individual warehouse level. WarehouseAvailability groups the stocks for two warehouses and adds the stock quantities.

Comment: @Venkataraman theres an error i come across here,  Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Column '105.255.132.248.SysproCompanyA.dbo.InvWarehouse.StockCode' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @MaureenSemadi, my bad. I have updated the query. please try again.